# How can I change my device's user name?

Tags: accounts, profiles

Modern Android devices (Android 13) show the username in the About screen:
[image]
But with no obvious way of changing it. This name is also shown in the "Accounts and Passwords" screen as a heading for the accounts tied to the user but again, with no obvious way of changing the value.
How is this field changed?

Comment: By user name, did you mean the one that is scratched off? If so, I'm not sure if it's universal. Pixel3a on Android 12 and Galaxy M12 on Android 13 don't have such info on the About page, only the device name which can be edited directly from there. I think it's better to also mention the manufacturer directly in the question.

Comment: Sorry, never mind... apparently it's also shown on [AOSP 9 custom ROM for Sony Xperia](https://i.imgur.com/HYQT4bf.png) and [stock Android 12 on Motorola Moto g52](https://www.91-img.com/gallery_images_uploads/1/1/115fe0c6d896228b76897cea632f0ff6f11cbd81.png). I think it's shown on most (near-)AOSP ROM :)

Comment: I appreciate the clarification, though

Answer (score 2):

Unintuitively, the user must first enable multiple user support on the device before the logged-in account can be configured. From the Settings menu, go to System, then "Multiple Users".

[image: System Settings]

[image: Multiple Users]

[image: Multiple Users Toggle]

Flick the toggle to ON and then click and hold your own profile to change the name it identifies as. When you're done, disable multiple users again. Changes will be immediate.

[image: Tap Current User]

[image: Change Username]

[image: Switch Toggle Off]

To Google engineers reading this: **make this more intuitive!**

This has been tested on Android 13 on Sony's build of Android and Stock Android 13 on an up-to-date Pixel phone. Older versions may behave differently.